# Units of $e^{-t}$ where $t$ is in seconds ; is there any units?

Tags: unit-of-measure

If you have $y = s^2 e^{-t}$ , what would the units be if $s$ is in meters and $t$ is in seconds, does $y$ even have units? Also what about $y=s^2  \ln(t)$, would you get the same answer ?

Comment: Units of $s$ must be $m^{-1/2}$

Comment: If $t$ is measured in seconds, there must be an implicit constant with units of "per second" in the exponent: The exponential series $\sum_{k} t^{k}/k!$ contains terms of every non-negative degree. Are you sure $e^{-t}$ doesn't refer to $1/e^{t}$, with $e^{t}$ in seconds, or something of that type?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it is not about mathematics.

Comment: @MattSamuel Dimensional analysis is very much part of mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transcendental functions such as $\exp$ and $\ln$ operate on and return pure numbers.  So $e^{-t}$ with $t$ in seconds doesn't really make sense; it should be $e^{-ct}$ where $c$ is in $\text{sec}^{-1}$.  Perhaps its numerical value happens to be $1\; \text{sec}^{-1}$.    And then $s^2 e^{-ct}$ would be in $\text{meters}^2$.

Comment: Technically, if you treat various units as gradations in a graded algebra, $e^{-t}$ with $t$ in seconds does make sense, although it is not homogeneous. I'm not a physicist, so I'm not sure if they even entertain dimensionally non-homogeneous expressions, but mathematically there is nothing wrong (or unusual, really) with it at all.